# Celery + Flask with SQLite as broker, error when calling task

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to get Flask to work with Celery with SQLite as backend. With the following code, however:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'sqla+sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'celery.db')

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

After starting a worker, [I get this error when trying to call a dummy task](http://pastebin.com/iHXxEFFd):

```
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Code:

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    t = add_together.delay(100,200)
    return str(t.wait())
```

What's wrong? I've tried googling any combination of Sqllite/SQLAlchemy/Flask/Celery, but have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: Google using the spelling _SQLite_ instead of _Sqllite_.

Answer (score 7):

As you can see in your trace, your app still trying to connect to rabbitmq-server. That means it's not configured properly. I didn't get why you're using `CELERY_BROKER_URL` instead of `BROKER_URL`. Quick solution may be, change this:

```
celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
```

to

```
celery = Celery(app.import_name,
                broker='sqla+sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'celery.db'),
                backend='db+sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'celery_results.db'))
```

Let's check how it works

Answer (score 0):

```
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

The error usually means the target port is unavailable or blocked by some sort of firewall.

```
File "C:\Users\Robus\banking_virtenv\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 95, in __init__
        raise socket.error(last_err)
    error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Looks like it is trying to connect using an AMQP transport. Please check your configuration.

Comment: Correct, I understand the error. However, shouldn't it be trying to use the sqlite database instead? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Robus That's my question too. It should try to use the SQLite, Not AMQP. So probably the issue is with how you configured Celery.